databricks asset bundle switch between run_as configs
Is it possible to switch neatly between user_name and service_principal_name.
I want to run dab from local terminal and pipeline deployment.
From terminal I want to use the user_name and from pipeline the service_principal_name.
I can neatly configure in databricks.yml and it runs as my user in every workspace i have defined it targets:
run_as:
  user_name: ${workspace.current_user.userName} 

But then for the pipeline i need to comment the line out and un-comment
    # run_as:
    #  service_principal_name: my_service_id

Making matters worse I can run in different databricks workspaces with my own user but for service_principal_name every ws has different name
Is there a way to handle this more elegantly?
EDIT:
Here is a simple example of what i mean:
databricks.yml
bundle:
  name: my-databricks-job
  databricks_cli_version: ">= 0.219.0"

include:
  - resources/*.yml
  - bundle.targets.yml

run_as:
  user_name: ${workspace.current_user.userName} # this needs to be commented
  # as in pipeline service_pricipal_name is used and all workspaces (dev/test/prod) has their own sp_name
  # but when running locally developers's name is used

variables:
  instance_profile_arn:
    description: instance profile arn from AWS
  cluster_policy_id:
    description: cluster policy id in databricks
  glue_catalog_id:
    description: glue catalog id in databricks spark conf
  deployment_mode:
    description: deployment mode (development/production)
    default: development # needs to be changed depending if I run locally or we are in pipeline -> this is needed for compute_id
  scheduling_status:
    description: flag enabling / disabling scheduling
    default: PAUSED
  service_principal_id:
    description: id for service principal
  app_package: 
    description: application package name and version for artifactory installation
    default: passlib==1.7.4 # a dummy package for local development. Need to change to actual app package when in pipeline.
  whl_path:
    description: path to built whl package
    default: ../dist/*.whl # this is the path where local build is and is taken from to upload to databrikcs

bundle.targets.yml (with only dev/prod)
targets:
  dev:
    mode: ${var.deployment_mode}
    default: false
    workspace:
      host: https://my-env-dev.cloud.databricks.com
      root_path: ${var.workspace_path}
    run_as:
      service_principal_name: ${var.service_principal_id} # in local mode this needs to be commented
    # compute_id: 0409-133807-czammgx0 # in local mode this needs to be uncommented, overrides resources job_cluster

    variables:
      instance_profile_arn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:instance-profile/my-service-pricipal-id-dev
      cluster_policy_id:
        lookup:
          cluster_policy: my-service-pricipal-id-dev
      glue_catalog_id: "XXXXX"
      service_principal_id:
        lookup:
          service_principal: "my-service-pricipal-id-dev"

  prod:
    mode: production
    workspace:
      host: https://my-env-prod.cloud.databricks.com
      root_path: ${var.workspace_path}
    run_as:
      service_principal_name: ${var.service_principal_id}

    variables:
      instance_profile_arn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:instance-profile/my-service-principal-prod
      cluster_policy_id:
        lookup:
          cluster_policy: my-service-principal-prod
      glue_catalog_id: "XXXXX"
      service_principal_id:
        lookup:
          service_principal: "my-service-principal-prod"
      scheduling_status: "UNPAUSED"


resources.yml
resources:
  jobs:
    my-databricks-job:
      name: my-databricks-job

      schedule:
        quartz_cron_expression: "0 30 9 * * ?"
        timezone_id: Europe/Helsinki
        pause_status: ${var.scheduling_status}

      tasks:
        - task_key: my-task-key
          python_wheel_task:
            package_name: my_package_name
            entry_point: my_entry_point
            parameters:
              - --environment
              - ${bundle.target}
          job_cluster_key: job_cluster
          libraries:
            # - whl: ${var.whl_path} # in local development this needs to be uncommented
            - pypi:
                package: ${var.app_package}
                repo: https://my-artifactory.com/api/pypi/py-general/simple/
          description:
            example

      job_clusters:
        - job_cluster_key: job_cluster
        .... some other configs no relevant


I could also add that with the whl package I need to change the version number on every deploy because if the name does not change, the existing cluster used in databricks won't update the package, even if the package actually changes in databricks workspace directory.

Can you provide more details like any error? configurations?

@RakeshGovindula No not really. There is no errors and this is all the configs. It just seems that you can't configure DAB to run neatly from local terminal with developers user name and then in pipeline with service principal. You have to comment out the sections from yaml depending what env you want to run in.

Have you tried using environment variables to switch between them. @eemilk

I've now added full context. Notice that in local development I use compute_id which is a existing cluster. It is much faster do develop with it because the it does not initialize on every deploy

Edit 1
why not using run as service principal on the top level in databricks.yml and override only with run as user name in the dev target? Also, you commented in your config file that the service principal is used to deploy to dev, I'm unsure of the purpose of this unless it's a dev int environment which isn't your physical dev?
For the compute id flag, the pattern is which can be combined with default variables to meet your needs:
Enables the use of --compute-id <cluster-id> in related calls to the bundle deploy command, which overrides any and all existing cluster definitions that are already specified in the related bundle configuration file. Instead of using --compute-id <cluster-id> in related calls to the bundle deploy command, you can set the compute_id mapping here, or as a child mapping of the bundle mapping, to the ID of the cluster to use.

Finally, if you are dead set on having run_as switches within your files, make separate files for local and pipeline deplo and use the name of the file as a param to set a variable for the includes in databricks.yml
Edit
I might have misunderstood your question. Perhaps you should re-think your deployment process if you are looking at a solution where you can deploy to a production environment from your local machine without editing your bundle definition. Or you could embed your DAB in a CI/CD pipeline system (which allows both local and cloud runs) and then make the switch between local and cloud credential at the CI/CD pipeline level (e.g. string replace within your yaml before running databricks cli or some other solution)
Original answer
As stated in the documentation, you need to do a targeted deployment:
bundle:
  name: my_targeted_bundle

run_as:
  service_principal_name: "..."

targets:
  # Development deployment settings, set as the default
  development:
    mode: development
    default: true
    workspace:
      host: ...
    run_as:
      user_name: eemilk@iki.fi

  # Production deployment settings
  production:
    mode: production
    workspace:
      host: ...
      root_path: ...
    run_as:
      service_principal_name: "..."


Yes I am doing local development in vs-code and building a whl package. When I have done what I need i push it to repository and it is taken to pipeline and published to test env.
I think it is essential that I can use local terminal for development also for the infrastructure, like with terraform. It should be parameterized so it is straight forward to switch between local and pipeline.
